# How to solve qtreeview decoration error

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I've got some strange behavior QTreeView + QAbstractItemModel. Tree data of my model is displayed correctly, but tree decoration is wrong, see attached picture (marked by red line). For item "System:s6" you can see additional line.

[image: tree]

I just wonder is it mistake of my model implementation or something else ? What could be wrong ?

UPD: Debug output of rowCount( QModelIndex & parent ) function

> ```
> "root rowCount:1"
> "b1 rowCount is:6" 
> "s1 rowCount is:0" 
> "s2 rowCount is:0" 
> "s3 rowCount is:0" 
> "s4 rowCount is:0" 
> "s5 rowCount is:0" 
> "s6 rowCount is:1" 
> "bs1 rowCount is:0"
> ```

UPD2: qt 4.8.0

Comment: IMO this is because of the error in your model. Looks like incorrect row count value. Can you show your model's code?

Comment: @vahancho it's first that came to my head and i've already tested rowCount results, seems, all correct. There are a lots of stuff in code, so i updated my post with rowCount debug output.

Comment: Maybe it also worth to check the parent/child relationship too?

Comment: @vahancho thanks for your assistance, I've found error. It was in my parent(QModelIndex &) function implementation. Parent index was returning with wrong row value.